# Compiling error with MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, build-error

I have always been able to use the MATLAB function block on simulink without problems, but ever since yesterday it has been giving me the message

> Unable to locate a C-compiler required by Stateflow and MATLAB Function blocks.
>   Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C-compiler.

After some search I tried installing Windows SDK, and reinstalling  Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express, but the error persists.

When I run the simulink model the following message appears on MATLAB's main window, before the first message appears on simulink

> Warning: ''MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   VSINSTALLDIR'
>    exceeds MATLAB's maximum name length of 63 characters and has
>    been truncated to
>    ''MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   o'.

I don't know if it they are connected, but the only recent change I made in this computer was installing MySQL in it.

Comment: What happens after a `mex -setup`? I strongly suspect you've got a path issue.

Comment: The error persists. I can choose the compiler, which it finds, in the setup, and the folder he uses seems to be the right one, but the same warnings appear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using windows (which it looks like from the question), type `!where mysql` on the Matlab command prompt. If the result is blank, you've got a path issue. Let's fix it.

First off, locate where your mysql executable lives -- either type `where mysql.exe` in a command shell, or just find it on the filesytem. Let's assume it's in `C:\Path\To\Mysql\`. Then, on the Matlab command prompt, change the PATH system variable by running:

setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ';C:\Path\To\Mysql\']);

Hopefully, that will work.

Comment: There was really no path defined, but, even after setting the Mysql path, both warnings still appear.